# I can't integrate a simple on scroll trigger for my JS counter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want the counter to start when I reach it during the scroll of the page. I'm using the same code than I found on Codepen, I checked if there is some problem in the html but I didn't find anything. I also looked for similar problems in the forum but I found nothing I could have been able to success with.

Basically the counter only works properly the first time one scrolls the page, if the page gets reloaded (tested in Firefox and Chrome) the counter doesn't start, it only starts with Firefox if after the reloading of the page, instead of restarting from the top of the page, the window is already showing the counter at the bottom of the page.

This is the code, where might I have gone wrong?

```js
   
var a = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {

  var oTop = $('#counter').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
  if (a == 0 && $(window).scrollTop() > oTop) {
    $('.counter-value').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this),
        countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
      $({
        countNum: $this.text()
      }).animate({
          countNum: countTo
        },

        {

          duration: 2000,
          easing: 'swing',
          step: function() {
            $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
          },
          complete: function() {
            $this.text(this.countNum);
            //alert('finished');
          }

        });
    });
    a = 1;
  }

});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}

#counters {
    font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#counter {
    position:relative;
    font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Through Fear</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400,600,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Space+Mono:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
        </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="container">
            <section class="children">
                <div class="row break">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row"><div class="three columns">s</div>
                  
                     <div class="six columns longtextsonblack">
        <p>sss<br>
        sss</p></div>
        <div class="three columns">s</div>
                     
                </div>
                </section>
            <section class="children">
            <div class="row break">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row"><div class="three columns">s</div>
                     <div class="six columns longtextsonblack">
        <p>
sss</p></div>
        <div class="three columns">s</div>
                </div>
           </section>
            <section class="children"><div class="row break">&nbsp;</div><div class="row"><div class="one column">s</div>
                <div class="one column">s</div>
            <div class="one column testiVerticali"><p>Fatturato</p></div>
    <div class="six columns longtextsonblack translate">
        <p>
            sss</p>
        <p>
            sss</p></div>
                <div class="three columns">s</div>
                <div class="row">
        <div class="one column centocinquanta">€</div>
<!--
        <div id="counters" class="eight columns"><div class="counter"data-target="150000000000">0
            </div>
        </div>
-->
             <div id="counter" class="eight columns counter-value" data-count="150000000">0
            
        </div>
                    
        <div class="two columns">s</div>
                    
                </div>
                </div>
                
            </section>
            
<div class="row"><div class="three columns">s</div>
                     <div class="six columns longtextsonblack">
        <p>
sss</p></div>
        <div class="three columns">s</div>
                    </div>
            
        
            
            
            </div>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/index.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
        
    </body>
    
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is occurring because you are scrolling on the container class, but detecting scrolls on the main document.

Assuming the container class is meant to take up the whole page, removing `overflow: scroll;` from its styling fixes the problem.

This causes the whole document to be scrolled instead of just the container class.

Comment: thank you very much man, i put the counter out of the .container div and inside a different div with scroll-behaviour: smooth, now it works!! :))